# Does OS X Yosemite tell you if you got your password wrong?

Tags: icloud, login

I just had, for no apparent reason, every Apple device decide that my iCloud account was faulty and I needed to re-sign-in on every device.  The first device I logged back into gave me "the third degree:" birthday, security questions, whole nine yards.

After that, I logged into iCloud separately via Web, and confirmed that my password is what I recall it to be.

However, over on my older OS X 10.10 Mac, I got no less than six popups asking for my iCloud password, so I had to type it a bunch of times.

**Why does it keep re-asking the password?** The password window indicates which app is asking, and several apps asked multiple times. (None of the apps are running at the time; it's iTunes, App Store and Facetime IIRC, none of which I use more than once a month).   When apps ask multiple times -- is that a different module within the app making a separate password request?  **Or am I mistyping my password and it's not telling me that?**

Because if it's failing my password silently, that spam of requests could quickly cause me to exceed my number of failed password tries, and then I'd need to reset the password. I've barely only memorized this one.

Comment: Wild guess is it doesn't understand the current protocols. I'm sure it would tell you if the password was wrong. How much further could you update that Mac? No Mac is stuck on 10.10 so you should be able to get to at least El Capitan, which might fare better, or High Sierra, which definitely understands the newer protocols.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have several older apps that barely work on 10.10 so prepping and validating a 10.11 image is a LOT of work. That's has high as my Mac can go.